# Odoo product quantity remaing the same after making an order in POS

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, odoo-9

Why doesn't the product quantity/inventory reduce in Odoo when you make a sale in Odoo POS system?

I had 5 units in inventory, I made a sale of 5 units. I checked back, and they were still 5. How do I ensure the product moves after selling it?

Comment: Did you get the solution for this? I am facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the solution on this link
[Odoo 11 POS 'sales do not decrease products ' stock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51185694/odoo-11-pos-sales-do-not-decrease-products-stock)

Install the warehouse restriction module and on the user profile, under "preference" tab, add the "delivery" operation on the "Default Warehouse Operations" field.